# How to test connectathon test in mac

Tags: macos, testing

I am running a tool called connectathon(cthon04) on my nac to test basic file operations but i'm getting struck in setting NFSTESTDIR value in some scripts in that cthon04 folder.

Let me know if any of you guys ever tried running cthon test on your mac,and how to set the value of NFSTESTDIR.

command ran:/cthon04/runtests -a -f

error:
NFSTESTDIR environment variable not set

Please let me know if any of you guys tried it,i am in need of it very badly

Answer (score 0):

I would try this in the terminal:

```
export NFSTESTDIR="Path/to/NFSTestDir"
```

That should set the environment variable for you.

Comment: thanks Chris for early response.
But where is NFSTESTDIR?? is it in some scripts like runtests/tests.init or you want me to create NFSTESTDIR variable in the path where i mounted in terminal.rights now i am mounted to cthon04 folder only.Let me know where to edit it

Comment: the good thing is the setting NFSTESTDIR went off but i'm now getting new error cthon04/runtests -a -f.It shows error-line 107 cd:basic:No such file or directory ,sh:runtests:no such file or drectory